# Razor MVC partial view cannot find end of code blocks and LI tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a partial view that is not rendering:

The designer is telling me 
     the foreach(Dress d in Model) is missing a closing character "}"
     the foreach(Picture p in d.Pictures) is missing a closing character "}"
     and the LI item is not closed

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Model.Dress>

        <ul class="thumbs noscript">
            @{                                                              
                foreach (Dress d in Model)
                { 
                    foreach(Picture p in d.Pictures)      
                    {                      
                        string dressPrefix = "images/Dresses/"+p.Dress.DressName;
                        string bigThumb = dressPrefix+"-"+p.Caption+"_bigthumb.jpg";
                        string thumb = dressPrefix+"-"+p.Caption+"_thumb.jpg";
                        string dressTitle = d.DressName+" "+d.Price.ToString();

                    <li>
                        <a class="thumb" href="@bigThumb" title="@dressTitle">
                            <img src="@thumb" alt=""@dressTitle" />
                        </a>
                    </li>                                                        
                    }
                }
            }
        </ul>

 public class Dress
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int GalleryTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual GalleryType GalleryType { get; set; }
        public int DressTypeID { get; set; }
        public virtual DressType DressType { get; set; }
        public int DesignerID { get; set; }
        public virtual Designer Designer { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DressName { get; set; }
        public string Bust { get; set; }
        public int DressLength { get; set; }
        public int SleeveLength { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int Waist { get; set; }
        public int test { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<DressColor> DressColors { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Picture> Pictures { get; set; }

    }

public class Picture
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Dress Dress { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string PictureURL { get; set; }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out hte extra braces, also you have an extra quote in the alt attribute of the img tag, which is probably what is causing your unclosed tag problem.

```
@model IEnumerable<MyApp.Model.Dress>

<ul class="thumbs noscript">
@foreach (Dress d in Model) { 
    foreach(Picture p in d.Pictures) {                      
        string dressPrefix = "images/Dresses/"+p.Dress.DressName;
        string bigThumb = dressPrefix+"-"+p.Caption+"_bigthumb.jpg";
        string thumb = dressPrefix+"-"+p.Caption+"_thumb.jpg";
        string dressTitle = d.DressName+" "+d.Price.ToString();

        <li>
            <a class="thumb" href="@bigThumb" title="@dressTitle">
                <img src="@thumb" alt="@dressTitle" />
            </a>
        </li>                                                        
    }
}
</ul>
```

FYI, you really shouldn't be doing that much code in your view, that should be in your controller.  You should also use string.Format to format the strings, not using the `+` operator.

Comment: Turns out it was an extra double-quote I had in the alt property - alt=""@dressTitle"

Comment: Yes, I know.  I told you that in my answer.

Comment: Sorry! I missed that! Marked as answer. I also I had to put the full name of the classes in both foreachs

    foreach(MyApp.Model.Dress d in Model)    
    foreach(MyApp.Model.Picture p in d.Pictures)

Comment: You can also just put a `@using` at the top, so `@using Myapp.Model`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your newly created variables are not being recognized by razor. You could just swap the variables by their expressions inside your `li` tag such as:
`title="@(d.DressName+" "+d.Price.ToString())"`.

Alternatively, you can take out the braces outside your foreach.

I would instead prefer creating a View Model to hold your prefix string and just using them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion on the view model, I plan on refactoring to use view models once I get the view working.

Comment: And I just learned that mvcscaffolding can scaffold viewmodels too!

Comment: Of course! A viewmodel and model are essentially simple classes with attributes. They only differ conceptually in terms of how they're consumed.